# OpenShift Logging: How do I make Kibana group lines of a stack trace into one record?

Tags: openshift, fluentd, efk

#### Context

I have the Red Hat OpenShift Logging Operator installed in a cluster, explained on [this page](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/logging/cluster-logging.html). This is basically an EFK stack (ElasticSearch, Fluentd, Kibana). Normally with Fluentd you can configure many plugins and hundreds of parameters, but as you can see on [this OpenShift page](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/logging/config/cluster-logging-collector.html#cluster-logging-collector-limits_cluster-logging-collector) there are only 9 Fluentd parameters available (all chunk-related) because the logging stack is packaged as a Red Hat Operator. Adding custom configuration is not an option for me because [it is unsupported](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/logging/config/cluster-logging-collector.html#cluster-logging-maintenance-support-about_cluster-logging-collector) and won't receive updates from RedHat.

#### Problem

When an application produces a stack trace after an error, Kibana shows **1 line of the stack trace per record** . I need the whole stack trace in 1 record. This is possible with the [Fluentd multiline plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline#java-stacktrace-log) but this is not a supported parameter with the Red Hat OpenShift Logging Operator (which uses Fluentd).

What are my options for grouping stack trace lines into one Kibana record, aside from installing a new/standalone logging stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a supported solution now:
[Multiline logs in OpenShift 4 with ClusterLogForwarder API](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5507871)

Comment: this applies to all multiline, or just multiline with errors?

Comment: @sloweriang If I understand you correctly, just multiline with errors. As far as i can remember `detectMultilineErrors` under-the-hood adds [fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions). The list of patterns is in [`exception_detector.rb`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-detect-exceptions/blob/17c846bc7e6f58f26794684cca9bd306d2f857cf/lib/fluent/plugin/exception_detector.rb).

Comment: so if I want not just multiline with errors, but also other multiline(e.g http post) , can openshift do it?

Comment: @sloweriang I think unfortunately this is not possible, no.

Comment: For the applications(s) my team is running we're currently migrating to JSON-Logging because some the plugin is picky what counts as an exception -- for example including correlation IDs in the log format lines breaks detection...